# Annotating the code with some colors or Labels

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was wondering if there is any adds-on or plugins for visual studio 2010 or 2012 that would allow me to color some lines of code with special color to annotation or for explaining to someone else , maybe put some labels on some lines or mark some lines with special fancy text

I know i can bookmark lines and put breakpoints but that not what i want, i was wondering if there is something more fancy and can be used to make more explanations.

Comment: Typically the better option would be to use the three slashes to insert XML documentation.  Just type "///" above your method, class, etc.

Comment: Im talking about annotating and labeling lines of codes not methods

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question Steve lol i know long methods are Code-Smell but im asking about something else :)

Comment: What is wrong with commenting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [source control tools such as TFS to annotate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx) individual lines.

[StickNotes](http://stickynotes4code.com/) for code is also another approach.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I could find for annotation in visual studio is http://stickynotes4code.com/

Hope this helps,